# cannot convert from "string" to "Photon.RealTime.AppSettings"

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

i am trying to make make a multiplayer game in unity using photon, but i am getting "cannot convert from "string" to "Photon.RealTime.AppSettings" " error. It's probably something stupid, so im sorry in advance.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;

public class MenuControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string VersionName = "0.1";
    [SerializeField] private GameObject UsernameMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject ConnectPanel;
    
    [SerializeField] private InputField UsernameInput;
    [SerializeField] private InputField CreateGameInput;
    [SerializeField] private InputField JoinGameInput;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        // Error happens here
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings(VersionName);
    }
    
    private void Start()
    {
        UsernameMenu.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby(TypedLobby.Default);
        Debug.Log("Connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which lines causes the problem? Also, this error happens cos there is no conversion between type `string` and `Photon.RealTime.AppSettings`. `string` is a simple text type while the latter one is probably a complex one.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation `PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings()` expects Type `AppSettings` but you are providing type `string`.

What you can do is simply using the correct type like `var appSettings = new AppSettings();`

Then assign the correct properties to this class and finally supply this object to `ConnectUsingSettings(appSettings)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a PUN Classic leftover code. As you can read on the [PUN Classic to PUN 2 Migration Notes](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/migration-notes#api_changes): "`PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings()` no longer takes `gameVersion` parameter. " And since AppSettings is an optional parameter simply call `PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings()` without parameters and PUN 2 will use PhotonServerSettings.